# TCP connection over IPv6 stuck in SYN_RCVD on AIX6.1

Tags: sockets, tcp, ipv6, aix

I have a program that accepts TCP connections over IPv4 and IPv6.
If a client connects via IPv4 everything works ok. However, if a client comes in through the IPv6 stack the TCP connection is not fully established but netstat shows the listening socket to be in the state SYN_RCVD. This happens on AIX 6.1

Is there anything I need to do/configure/forgot?
Following are the essential bits of my code that deal with the socket handling:

```
/*
 * If IPv4 and IPv6 are supported simultaneously
 *   we use the IPv6 socket because it can handle both
 */
for (AI = AddrInfo; AI != NULL; AI = AI->ai_next)
{
    /* Only PF_INET and PF_INET6 are supported. */
    if ((AI->ai_family != PF_INET) && (AI->ai_family != PF_INET6))
        continue;
    NumSocks++;
}
if (NumSocks == 0)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Function %s failed. Error: %s\n",
              fktName, "unable to serve on any address.\n" );
   return -1;
}
if (NumSocks > 1)
{
  /* if we have more than 1 IPv4/IPv6-interface find the IPv6 interface */
  for (AI = AddrInfo; AI != NULL; AI = AI->ai_next)
  {
      if (AI->ai_family == PF_INET6) {
          break;
      }
  }
}
if (AI == NULL)
{
  /* we only have 1 interface or no IPv6 interface */
  AI = AddrInfo;
}

/* Open a socket with the correct address family for this address. */
newsock = socket(AI->ai_family, AI->ai_socktype, AI->ai_protocol);
if (newsock < 0)
{
  fprintf(stdout, "Function %s returned with return code = %s\n",
            "socket()", strerror(tcperrno()));
  return -1;
}

/* Allows the socket to be bound to an address that is already in use */
val = 1;
if (setsockopt(newsock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,SPCHAR & val,(s_sock) sizeof(val)))
{
     fprintf(stdout, "Function %s returned with return code = %s\n",
               "setsockopt(newsock)", strerror(tcperrno()));
    }
    SOCK_CLOSE(newsock);
    return -1;
}

/* Bind the socket to a local address and port */
if (bind(newsock, AI->ai_addr, (int) AI->ai_addrlen) < 0)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "Function %s failed. Error: %s\n",
           "bind(newsock)", strerror(tcperrno()));
  SOCK_CLOSE(newsock);
  return -1;
}

/* Listen for incomming connections. */
if (listen(newsock, SOMAXCONN) < 0)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Function %s failed. Error: %s\n",
            "listen(newsock)", strerror(tcperrno()));
  SOCK_CLOSE(newsock);
  return -1;
}
:
/* Accept a connection.  */
mysock = accept(newsock, CAST_TCP & client, &namelen);
:
```

According to truss my process never returns from accept().

Comment: Your code sample appears to be [incomplete](http://sscce.org/). It also seems to have some garbage characters in it. Try providing a complete, compilable example which demonstrates the problem.